# How to get the formatter used for specific code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatter

I am writing a web frontend with Typescript, Vue.js, Vite and Quasar. Because of this I have a stack of suggested extensions, some of which format the code.

In my code I have code such as

```
<q-input rounded outlined id="id-input" v-model="personId"
    label="If you have an ID type it here, otherwise go to User panel on the right to generate a new one"
    class="col-9 id-font" :rules="[val => isIdValid(personId) || 'Invalid ID']" ref="idInputRef">
</q-input>
```

I would like it to be formatted as

```
<q-input 
  rounded 
  outlined 
  id="id-input" 
  v-model="personId"
  label="If you have an ID type it here, otherwise go to User panel on the right to generate a new one"
  class="col-9 id-font" 
  :rules="[val => isIdValid(personId) || 'Invalid ID']" 
  ref="idInputRef"
>
</q-input>
```

but the formatter is set to squeeze as many properties as possible in a single line.

**My question:** how can I find out what this formatter is so that I can look at how to configure it?